# Where did the Kyber crystals come from?

Tags: star-wars

Where did the kyber crystals come from, and why didn't any common man have a lightsaber?

Comment: I fixed your question up a bit, but I'm not certain if I split it at the right part. It looked like you had two questions, but I wasn't certain which one "if they were rare" was supposed to modify, so I guessed.

Comment: And as it currently stands, you have two questions, and you might be best off creating another question for why lightsabres were not in use among common people.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Is there a shortage of Kyber crystals in the galaxy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/166919/31394)

Comment: Related: [From where did Luke get kyber crystals to build a lightsaber?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/154406/31394)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9874/do-non-jedi-and-non-sith-use-lightsabers is also an answer to the second question.

Comment: Incidentally, with a bit of time away, do you feel like you have a clearer idea of your question?

Comment: No i think i got my answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Kyber Crystals](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal)

> Kyber crystals were Force-attuned crystals that grew rarely but throughout the galaxy, with some areas having a greater abundance than others. The crystals concentrated energy in a unique manner through the Force, resonating with it. The crystals exhibited a sort of "collective consciousness," verging on sentience, and could non-verbally communicate with both one another and living beings. Some theorized that the permutations in the kyber lattice were comparable to emotional shifts in a sentient being.

There do exist [Synthetic Kyber Crystals](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Synthetic_kyber_crystal), which were less stable.

> Synthetic kyber crystals were artificial kyber crystals,[1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal) Force-attuned crystals that were used by the Jedi and Sith in the construction of their lightsabers, that glowed with a green hue. Due to their synthetic nature, they were highly unstable and explosive, and possession of them was made illegal by the Galactic Empire.

Comment: If the crystals were rare then why doesnt a common being has been shown with a kyber crystel

Comment: @MKX: I'm not certain what you mean. If they are rare, it would be less likely for a common person to show up with a Kyber crystal, since they're likely to be highly controlled in those rare locations by the people who can make the best use of them.

Comment: You know i should probably stop asking for few days you know sometimes even i cant understand myself

Comment: @MKX: Pacing one's questions can be useful. :) If nothing else, it reduces the chance of rep capping if it comes out to be popular.

Comment: @MKX "Normal" people have been shown with Kyber crystals. Jyn Erso has a kyber necklace in *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*. An Ithorian "normal person" character named Dok-Ondar, created for Disney's theme parks but also appearing in comics and is present-but-offscreen for *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, sells kyber crystals in his shop on Batuu.